# How does the ssh server select the right public key?

Tags: ssh, openssh

For key-based auth users must add their public keys to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. This file can contain a number of keys, one per line. So how the server selects the right key to authenticate a user with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/abd59663df37a42152e37980113ccaa405b9a282/auth2-pubkey.c#L265), it just loops over all keys until a matching key is found:

```c
process_principals(FILE *f, const char *file, struct passwd *pw,
    const struct sshkey_cert *cert)
{
//...

    while (read_keyfile_line(f, file, line, sizeof(line), &linenum) != -1) {
        /* Always consume entire input */
        if (found_principal)
            continue;
//...
        for (i = 0; i < cert->nprincipals; i++) {
            if (strcmp(cp, cert->principals[i]) == 0) {
                debug3("%s:%lu: matched principal \"%.100s\"",
                    file, linenum, cert->principals[i]);
                if (auth_parse_options(pw, line_opts,
                    file, linenum) != 1)
                    continue;
                found_principal = 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return found_principal;
}
```